# Finding the coordinates of the fourth vertex of tetrahedron, given coordinates of "base" vertices and the distances to them

Tags: geometry, 3d

I have a tetrahedron defined as:

- "base" vertices $P$, $Q$, $R$ are given.
- length of "remain" edges $L_P$, $L_Q$, and $L_R$ are also given.

I need to find the 4th vertex coordinates $(x, y, z)$. The image below describes my problem:

[image]

I understand that there are two symmetric solutions, one where the vertex is up and another when the vertex is below the plane defined by $(P, Q, R)$.

I tried to solve this problem by considering 3 spheres $S_P$, $S_Q$, $S_R$ with center on $P$, $Q$, $R$ and radius $L_P$, $L_Q$, and $L_R$, respectively. I'm wondering if there is an easier straighforward way to solve this.

Comment: An obvious algebraic way of doing this would be to write down the equations for the three spheres, call them $E_P$, $E_Q$ and $E_R$. When you subtract $E_Q$ and $E_R$ from $E_P$, the quadratic terms cancel. This gives you equations of two planes. You can solve for two of the coordinates in terms of the third. Plugging those into $E_P$ leaves you a single variable quadratic equation, and you can use the quadratic formula.

Comment: I think those planes would be the ones through the fourth vertex and orthogonal to $PQ$ and $PR$ respectively. Pythagoras says on such a plane $L_P^2-L_Q^2$ is constant, no?

Comment: Hi, @JyrkiLahtonen, this way using spheres was my first attempt. I'm wondering me if there is an straightforward way to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finding $(x, y, z)$ as the intersection of three spheres of radius $L_P$, $L_Q$, and $L_R$, centered at $P = (P_x, P_y, P_z)$, $Q = (Q_x, Q_y, Q_z)$, and $R = (R_x, R_y, R_z)$, respectively, is the solution.

However, if you rotate and translate the coordinate system, you can simplify the math a lot.  (This is nothing special; it's just that when most of the coordinates are zeroes, the expressions simplify a lot.)

Rotate and translate the coordinate system (we'll use $(u, v, w)$ for the rotated and translated coordinates for clarity; note that distances are unchanged), $P$ is at origin $(0, 0, 0)$, $Q$ is at $(U_Q, 0, 0)$, and $R$ at $(U_R, V_R, 0)$. Then, the fourth vertex is at
$$\begin{aligned}
u &= \frac{L_P^2 - L_Q^2 + U_Q^2}{2 U_Q} \\
v &= \frac{L_P^2 - L_R^2 + U_R^2 + V_R^2 - 2 U_R u}{2 V_R} \\
w &= \pm\sqrt{L_P^2 - u^2 - v^2} \\
\end{aligned}$$

Rotating and translating the coordinate system is not difficult, either:
$$\begin{aligned}
U_Q &= \left\lVert Q - P \right\rVert \\
\hat{u} &= \frac{Q - P}{U_Q} \\
\vec{t} &= (R - P) - \hat{u}\bigr(\hat{u} \cdot (R - P)\bigr) \\
\hat{v} &= \frac{\vec{t}}{\left\lVert \vec{t} \right\rVert} \\
\hat{w} &= \hat{u} \times \hat{v} \\
U_R &= (R - P) \cdot \hat{u} \\
V_R &= (R - P) \cdot \hat{v} \\
\end{aligned}$$
Conversion back to original coordinates is similarly trivial:
$$\vec{p} = P + u \hat{u} + v \hat{v} + w \hat{w}$$

---

Here is a Python 3 implementation:

```
# SPDX-License-Identifier: CC0-1.0
# This file is in Public Domain.

from vector import Vector, sqrt

def find_fourth_vertex(vertex1, vertex2, vertex3, distance1, distance2, distance3):
    # Use Vector type for the vertices
    p1 = Vector(vertex1[0], vertex1[1], vertex1[2])
    p2 = Vector(vertex2[0], vertex2[1], vertex2[2])
    p3 = Vector(vertex3[0], vertex3[1], vertex3[2])

    # Use float type for the distances
    r1 = float(distance1)
    r2 = float(distance2)
    r3 = float(distance3)

    u_axis = (p2 - p1).unit
    v_axis = (p3 - p1).perp(u_axis).unit
    w_axis = u_axis ^ v_axis

    u2 = (p2 - p1) | u_axis
    u3 = (p3 - p1) | u_axis
    v3 = (p3 - p1) | v_axis

    u = (r1*r1 - r2*r2 + u2*u2) / (2*u2)
    v = (r1*r1 - r3*r3 + u3*u3 + v3*v3 - 2*u*u3) / (2*v3)
    w = sqrt(r1*r1 - u*u - v*v)

    return (p1 + u*u_axis + v*v_axis + w*w_axis,
            p1 + u*u_axis + v*v_axis - w*w_axis)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from math import sin, cos, pi
    from random import Random

    prng = Random()

    while True:
        # Generate four random vectors in (-9.9,-9.9,-9.9) - (+9.9,+9.9,+9.9)
        v = [ Vector(prng.uniform(-9.9, 9.9), prng.uniform(-9.9, 9.9), prng.uniform(-9.9, 9.9)),
              Vector(prng.uniform(-9.9, 9.9), prng.uniform(-9.9, 9.9), prng.uniform(-9.9, 9.9)),
              Vector(prng.uniform(-9.9, 9.9), prng.uniform(-9.9, 9.9), prng.uniform(-9.9, 9.9)),
              Vector(prng.uniform(-9.9, 9.9), prng.uniform(-9.9, 9.9), prng.uniform(-9.9, 9.9)) ]
        # Find their minimum pairwise distance
        rmin = (v[1] - v[0]).norm
        for i in range(0, len(v) - 1):
            for j in range(i+1, len(v)):
                rmin = min(rmin, (v[j] - v[i]).norm)
        # If they're all least 1 unit from each other, accept.
        if rmin >= 1:
            break

    v1 = v[0]
    v2 = v[1]
    v3 = v[2]

    r1 = (v[3] - v[0]).norm
    r2 = (v[3] - v[1]).norm
    r3 = (v[3] - v[2]).norm

    print("v1 = %s, distance %f" % (v1, r1))
    print("v2 = %s, distance %f" % (v2, r2))
    print("v3 = %s, distance %f" % (v3, r3))

    v4a, v4b = find_fourth_vertex(v1, v2, v3, r1, r2, r3)

    print("v4 == %s" % (v[3],))
    print("v4a = %s" % (v4a,))
    print("v4b = %s" % (v4b,))

    print("v4a distances: %f, %f, %f" % ((v4a-v1).norm, (v4a-v2).norm, (v4a-v3).norm))
    print("v4b distances: %f, %f, %f" % ((v4b-v1).norm, (v4b-v2).norm, (v4b-v3).norm))
```

where `a.perp(b)` is $\vec{a} - \vec{b}(\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b})$, `a | b` is $\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b}$ and `a ^ b` is $\vec{a} \times \vec{b}$.

When run, it generates a test tetrahedron, and displays the results when `find_fourth_vertex` is given three of the vertices and their distances to the fourth.

The helper Vector class is implemented by `vector.py`:

```
# SPDX-License-Identifier: CC0-1.0
# This file is in Public Domain.

from math import sqrt

class Vector(tuple):
    """Tuple subclass implementing basic 3D vectors"""

    def __new__(cls, x, y, z):
        return tuple.__new__(cls, (float(x), float(y), float(z)))

    def perp(self, other):
        """Part perpendicular to other vector"""
        dp = self[0]*other[0] + self[1]*other[1] + self[2]*other[2]
        return Vector(self[0] - dp*other[0],
                      self[1] - dp*other[1],
                      self[2] - dp*other[2])

    @property
    def unit(self):
        """Scaled to unit length"""
        n = sqrt(self[0]*self[0] + self[1]*self[1] + self[2]*self[2])
        return Vector(self[0]/n, self[1]/n, self[2]/n)

    @property
    def norm(self):
        """Euclidean length"""
        return sqrt(self[0]*self[0] + self[1]*self[1] + self[2]*self[2])

    @property
    def normsqr(self):
        """Euclidean length squared"""
        return self[0]*self[0] + self[1]*self[1] + self[2]*self[2]

    @property
    def x(self):
        """Vector x coordinate"""
        return self[0]

    @property
    def y(self):
        """Vector y coordinate"""
        return self[1]

    @property
    def z(self):
        """Vector z coordinate"""
        return self[2]

    def __bool__(self):
        """Nonzero vector"""
        return (self[0]*self[0] + self[1]*self[1] + self[2]*self[2] > 0)

    def __abs__(self):
        """abs(a): Euclidean length of vector a"""
        return sqrt(self[0]*self[0] + self[1]*self[1] + self[2]*self[2])

    def __add__(self, other):
        """a + b: Vector addition"""
        if isinstance(other, (tuple, list)) and len(other) >= 3:
            return Vector(self[0]+other[0], self[1]+other[1], self[2]+other[2])
        else:
            return NotImplemented

    def __radd__(self, other):
        """b + a: Vector addition"""
        if isinstance(other, (tuple, list)) and len(other) >= 3:
            return Vector(other[0]+self[0], other[1]+self[1], other[2]+self[2])
        else:
            return NotImplemented

    def __mul__(self, other):
        """a * b: Scalar multiplication"""
        if isinstance(other, (int, float)):
            return Vector(self[0]*other, self[1]*other, self[2]*other)
        else:
            return NotImplemented

    def __rmul__(self, other):
        """b * a: Scalar multiplication"""
        if isinstance(other, (int, float)):
            return Vector(other*self[0], other*self[1], other*self[2])
        else:
            return NotImplemented

    def __neg__(self):
        """-a: Negation"""
        return Vector(-self[0], -self[1], -self[2])

    def __or__(self, other):
        """a | b: Dot product"""
        if isinstance(other, (tuple, list)) and len(other) >= 3:
            return self[0]*other[0] + self[1]*other[1] + self[2]*other[2]
        else:
            return NotImplemented

    def __ror__(self, other):
        """b | a: Dot product"""
        if isinstance(other, (tuple, list)) and len(other) >= 3:
            return other[0]*self[0] + other[1]*self[1] + other[2]*self[2]
        else:
            return NotImplemented

    def __sub__(self, other):
        """a - b: Vector subtraction"""
        if isinstance(other, (tuple, list)) and len(other) >= 3:
            return Vector(self[0]-other[0], self[1]-other[1], self[2]-other[2])
        else:
            return NotImplemented

    def __rsub__(self, other):
        """b - a: Vector subtraction"""
        if isinstance(other, (tuple, list)) and len(other) >= 3:
            return Vector(other[0]-self[0], other[1]-self[1], other[2]-self[2])
        else:
            return NotImplemented

    def __truediv__(self, other):
        """a / b: Scalar division"""
        if isinstance(other, (int, float)):
            return Vector(self[0]/other, self[1]/other, self[2]/other)
        else:
            return NotImplemented

    def __xor__(self, other):
        """a ^ b: Vector cross product"""
        if isinstance(other, (tuple, list)) and len(other) >= 3:
            return Vector(self[1]*other[2] - self[2]*other[1],
                          self[2]*other[0] - self[0]*other[2],
                          self[0]*other[1] - self[1]*other[0])
        else:
            return NotImplemented

    def __rxor__(self, other):
        """b ^ a: Vector cross product"""
        if isinstance(other, (tuple, list)) and len(other) >= 3:
            return Vector(other[1]*self[2] - other[2]*self[1],
                          other[2]*self[0] - other[0]*self[2],
                          other[0]*self[1] - other[1]*self[0])
        else:
            return NotImplemented
```

that you can just put in the same directory as the example Python file.
Run `pydoc3 vector` in that directory to see the API description for it.

Note that `vector.py` defines a generic 3D Euclidean vector class with basic vector algebra operations, and is in no way specific to this particular problem.

Comment: Should I add the derivation for $u$, $v$, $w$ (when the other three vertices are $(0,0,0)$, $(U_Q,0,0)$, and $(U_R, V_R, 0)$)?  It is all really straightforward.  Choosing the correct coordinate system to solve the problem in makes a really big difference in the actual calculation, and should not be overlooked in problems like this.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I didn't run the program but I know this method of spheres intersection actually works,

Comment: @Duloren: Yup, it's quite bog-standard trilateration.

Answer (score 1):

After some work on my own question, I think I have found an alternative way to solve this problem.

The objective is to find the vertex $E$ of a [tetrahedron](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Tetrahedron.html) defined as:

- Points $P$, $Q$ and $R$
- Distances $||\vec{PE}||$, $||\vec{QE}||$ and $||\vec{RE}||$

In this solution, $E$ can be achieved by finding the angles $\sigma$ and $\theta$ in order to construct a vector $\vec{PE}$.

[image]

Note that $\theta$ is the angle between the unknow vector $\vec{PE}$ and the plane defined by the points $P$, $Q$ and $R$. $\sigma$ is the angle between the projection of $\vec{PE}$ on the same plane $PQR$ and the vector $\vec{PR}$.

As the image suggests, $\sigma$ and $\theta$ can be obtained in a straightforward way from the tetrahedron height and elementary trigonometric properties, as shown below.

**Finding $\vec{PE}$ angles $\sigma$ and $\theta$**

1. Find the tetrahedron $Volume$ using [Calyer-Menger determinant](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cayley-MengerDeterminant.html):

$$288 Volume^2 = \left|\begin{matrix}0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\cr 1 & 0 & ||\vec{RE}||^{2} & ||\vec{PE}||^{2} & ||\vec{QE}||^{2}\cr 1 & ||\vec{RE}||^{2} & 0 & \tilde||\vec{QE}||^{2} & \tilde||\vec{PE}||^{2}\cr 1 & ||\vec{PE}||^{2} & \tilde||\vec{QE}||^{2} & 0 & \tilde||\vec{RE}||^{2}\cr 1 & ||\vec{QE}||^{2} & \tilde||\vec{PE}||^{2} & \tilde||\vec{RE}||^{2} & 0\end{matrix}\right|$$

2. Find the $Area$ of triangle $P$, $Q$, $R$ using [Heron's formula](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HeronsFormula.html):

$$Area = \frac{1}{4}\sqrt{4||\vec{PE}||^2||\vec{QE}||^2-(||\vec{PE}||^2+||\vec{QE}||^2-||\vec{RE}||^2)^2}$$

3. Find the tetrahedron height $H$ using the relationship between $Volume$ and $Area$:

$$H = \frac{3\times Volume}{Area}$$

4. Find $\theta$:

$$\theta = arcsin\left (\frac{H}{||\vec{PE}||}\right )$$

Once we have $\theta$ the next step is to find the length of the projections $\vec{PE'}$ and $\vec{RE'}$ onto the plane defined by $P$, $Q$ and $R$:

[image]

$$||\vec{PE'}|| = \sqrt{||\vec{PE}||^2 - H^2}$$
$$||\vec{RE'}|| = \sqrt{||\vec{RE}||^2 - H^2}$$

5. Thus, using the [cosine law](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LawofCosines.html), $\sigma$ is given by:

$$\sigma = arccos\left (\frac{||\vec{PE'}||^2 - ||\vec{RE'}||^2 + ||\vec{PR}||^2}{2 ||\vec{PE'}|| \times ||\vec{PR}||}\right )$$

Once we have $P$, $||\vec{PE}||$, $\sigma$ and $\theta$ we know everything we need to find $E$.

**Finding $E$ given $\sigma$, $\theta$, $P$ and $||\vec{PE}||$**

There are several ways to obtain $E(x, y, z)$, one of them is rotating $\vec{PR}$ by $\sigma$ and then rotating again by $\theta$, as demonstrated below.

1. Find the triangle $PQR$ normal $\vec{n}$:

$$\vec{n} = \frac{\vec{PR}\times\vec{PQ}}{||\vec{PR}|| \times ||\vec{PQ}||}$$

2. Rotate $\vec{PR}$ about $\vec{n}$ by $-\sigma$ using [Rodrigues' formula](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RodriguesRotationFormula.html):

$$\vec{PE'} = \vec{PR}cos(-\sigma) + (\vec{n} \times \vec{PR})\sin(-\sigma) + \vec{n}(\vec{n} \cdot \vec{PR}) (1 - cos(-\sigma))$$

3. Find the normal $\vec{m}$ from $\vec{PE'}$ and $\vec{n}$:

$$\vec{m} = \frac{\vec{PE'}\times\vec{n}}{||\vec{PE'}|| \times ||\vec{n}||}$$

4. Rotate $\vec{PE'}$ by $-\theta$ about $\vec{m}$:

$$\vec{PE_{dir}} = \vec{PE'}cos(-\theta) + (\vec{m} \times \vec{PE'})\sin(-\theta) + \vec{m}(\vec{m} \cdot \vec{PE'}) (1 - cos(-\theta))$$

5. Get the unit vector from $\vec{PE_{dir}}$ and multiply it by $||\vec{PE}||$ in order to obtain $\vec{PE}$:

$$\vec{PE} = \frac{\vec{PE_{dir}}}{||\vec{PE_{dir}}||} \times ||\vec{PE}||$$

Finally, $E$ is given by

$$E = \vec{PE} + P$$

It is noteworthy that the symmetric solution $E_2$ can be find by rotating $\vec{PE'}$ about $\vec{m}$ by $+\theta$ (instead of $-\theta$):

[image: symmetric solutions]

One of my future work is checking out if this approach is less computational intensive than others.

Follow some images from an experiment where $E$ is obtained by the procedure described here. This program can be visualized here: https://doleron.github.io/tetrahedron-4th-vertex/ and the source code is here: https://github.com/doleron/tetrahedron-4th-vertex

[image]

[image]

[image]

Note that the spheres are there only for comparision purposes.