# Find 4th vertex of tetrahedron given 3 vertices and 3 angles

Tags: geometry, vectors, 3d, solid-geometry

I have a tetrahedron which I know the coordinates of 3 vertices $PQR$ and I need to calculate the coordinate of the 4th vertex $E$ since I know the angles around $E$: $\theta_0$, $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$:

[image: tetrahedron PQRE]

I tried to solve this by defining a system:

$$\cos{\theta_0}=\frac{\vec{ER} \cdot \vec{EP}}{||\vec{ER}\||||\vec{EP}||}$$
$$\cos{\theta_1}=\frac{\vec{ER} \cdot \vec{EQ}}{||\vec{ER}\||||\vec{EQ}||}$$
$$\cos{\theta_2}=\frac{\vec{EP} \cdot \vec{EQ}}{||\vec{EP}\||||\vec{EQ}||}$$

with no success. I appreciate if someone can provide some help.

Comment: I see at least two approaches, in either way the result won't be simple. 1) letting $|ER|,\,|EP|,\,|EQ|$ as unknowns and considering cosine rule for triangles $EPR,\,ERQ,\,EQP$ we have $3$ equations on these unknowns, hence we have $|ER|,\,|EP|,\,|EQ|$. Now we solve a system where $E$ coordinates are unknown with already obtained $3$ equations on $|ER|,\,|EP|,\,|EQ|$, so we're done. 2) Consider locus of $E$ such that $\angle PEQ=\theta_2$ (in planar case it's two arcs as $\angle PEQ$ is inscribed and known), hence find $E$ as intersection of the three such loci. Does it all make sense? Thanks.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin about 1) By using cosine law I ended up with a system like the one using angles between vectors. Do you tried solving it? about 2) I didn't get you sorry.

Comment: You can find the three spheres as related to the angle view of the segments and attempt the solution for the three equations. You will get two answers as expected.

Comment: @Moti since I don't know the spheres radius I can't see how approaching this specific problem as a sphere intersection problem can help me.

Comment: I think you can work out the radii of those spheres. Again, consider the plane $T$ of, say, $E,R,P$. Let $O_1$ be the center of the circular arc of the loci of candidate points $E$ on $T$ with the property that $\angle PER=\theta_0$. By a well known theorem (sorry, I don't remember the terms in English), we have $\angle POR=2\theta_0$, and $|OR|=|OP|$. The radius of the circle is thus $r_0=\dfrac12|RP|\sin\theta_0.$ Observe that this only depends on $\theta_0$, so it must the radius of the sphere also.

Comment: @Moti They won't be spheres. They are more like self-intersecting torii, namely what you get when rotating a circle about a chord.

Comment: I would attempt a "flattened approach", i.e.,  transfer the 3D problem into a 2D problem : how to create the tetrahedron out of a flat cardboard, beginning by drawing triangle $PQR$, then, on each side (attempt to) create triangles $PQE_1$,$QRE_2$, $RPE_3$ with isosceles  triangles $E_1PE_3$,  $E_1QE_2$, $E_2RE_3$ meeting the angles requirements...

Comment: @Jaap you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a full answer, but perhaps someone better at maths could complete this?

Without any loss in generality, we can rotate, translate, and scale the coordinate system so that $P$ is at origin $(0, 0, 0)$, $Q$ is at $(1, 0, 0)$, $R$ is at $(\chi, \gamma, 0)$, and the fourth vertex $E$ is at $(x, y, z)$.

We can do this via constructing the new orthonormal basis vectors $\hat{u}$, $\hat{v}$, $\hat{w}$ via
$$\begin{aligned}
L &= \lVert Q - P \rVert \\
\hat{u} &= \frac{Q - P}{L} \\
\vec{v} &= R - P - \hat{u}\bigr(\hat{u}\cdot(R - P)\bigr) \\
\hat{v} &= \frac{\vec{v}}{\lVert\vec{v}\rVert} \\
\hat{w} &= \hat{u} \times \hat{v} \\
\end{aligned}$$
such that
$$\begin{aligned}
\chi &= \frac{1}{L}(R - P) \cdot \hat{u} \\
\gamma &= \frac{1}{L}(R - P) \cdot \hat{v} \\
E &= P + L x \hat{u} + L y \hat{v} + L z \hat{w} \\
\end{aligned}$$

The three edge vectors from $E$ to $P$, $Q$, and $R$, respectively, are
$$\begin{aligned}
\vec{e}_P &= (-x, -y, -z) \\
\vec{e}_Q &= (1 - x, -y, -z) \\
\vec{e}_R &= (\chi - x, \gamma - y, -z) \\
\end{aligned}$$
and assuming a non-degenerate tetrahedron with nonzero edge lengths, the three angles $\theta_{PQ}$, $\theta_{PR}$, and $\theta_{QR}$ fulfill
$$\left\lbrace ~\begin{aligned}
\cos(\theta_{PQ}) &= \frac{ \vec{e}_P \cdot \vec{e}_Q }{ \lVert\vec{e}_P\rVert \lVert\vec{e}_Q\rVert } \\
\cos(\theta_{PR}) &= \frac{ \vec{e}_P \cdot \vec{e}_R }{ \lvert\vec{e}_P\rVert \lVert\vec{e}_R\rVert } \\
\cos(\theta_{QR}) &= \frac{ \vec{e}_Q \cdot \vec{e}_R }{ \lvert\vec{e}_Q\rVert \lVert\vec{e}_R\rVert } \\
\end{aligned}\right.$$
In Cartesian coordinate form, this is
$$\left\lbrace ~ \begin{aligned}
\cos(\theta_{PQ}) &= \frac{ x (x - 1) + y^2 + z^2 }{\sqrt{ \bigr( x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \bigr) \bigr( (x-1)^2 + y^2 + z^2 \bigr) }} \\
\cos(\theta_{PR}) &= \frac{ x (x - \chi) + y (y - \gamma) + z^2 }{\sqrt{ \bigr( x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \bigr) \bigr( (x - \chi)^2 + (y - \gamma)^2 + z^2 \bigr) }} \\
\cos(\theta_{QR}) &= \frac{ (x - 1)(x - \chi) + y (y - \gamma) + z^2}{\sqrt{\bigr( (x-1)^2 + y^2 + z^2 \bigr)\bigr( (x - \chi)^2 + (y - \gamma)^2 + z^2 \bigr) }} \\ 
\end{aligned} \right.$$
Unfortunately, my laptop overheated before Maxima could find a solution to the above.

If we use $d^2 = x^2 + y^2 + z^2$ as shorthand, then
$$\left\lbrace ~ \begin{aligned}
\cos(\theta_{PQ}) &= \frac{d^2 - x}{d\sqrt{d^2 + 1 - 2 x}} \\
\cos(\theta_{PR}) &= \frac{d^2 - \chi x - \gamma y}{d\sqrt{d^2 - \chi ( 2 x - \chi) - \gamma ( 2 y - \gamma ) }} \\
\cos(\theta_{QR}) &= \frac{d^2 + \chi - x - \chi x - \gamma y}{\sqrt{\big( d^2 + 1 - 2 x \big)\big( d^2 - \chi ( 2 x - \chi) - \gamma ( 2 y - \gamma ) \big)}} \\
\end{aligned} \right.$$
so perhaps we should try and solve for $x/d$, $y/d$, and $z/d$ first, via a change in variables?

Comment: Hi @None. Thanks. I'm trying to figure out how to derive the other 2 angles of each faces by using the PQR normal.

Comment: @Duloren: $EPQ$ is a triangle with circumradius $2 r_{PQ}$, $$\frac{\lVert P - Q \rVert}{\sin(\theta_{PQ})} = 2 r_{PQ}$$and since $P$ and $Q$ are on that circle, we have the surface of a torus (as the circle is swept around the $PQ$ axis). Similarly for the two other sides. So, essentially we have three circles that can rotate freely around one axis each, with $E$ located where all three intersect.  If we measure the rotation angles from the $PQR$ plane, then we immediately have the normals for each triangular face; *and vice versa*.  Perhaps we could derive those angles from the known ones?

Comment: @Duloren: I mean, working backwards, when the three normals or rotation angles (included angles at edges $PQ$, $PR$, and $QR$) are known, calculating the angles at $E$, to see if there are invertible equations describing the relationship.

Comment: @Duloren: This approach didn't lead to an answer, but going back to basics, to triangles, did.  I posted that as a separate answer, so this one can be ignored.

Comment: Okay @none. Thank you for the explanations. I m reading everything you wrote and trying to solve this challenging scenario.

Answer (score 1):

For clarity, let
$$\begin{aligned}
L_{PQ} &= \lVert Q - P \rVert, \\
L_{PR} &= \lVert R - P \rVert, \\
L_{QR} &= \lVert R - Q \rVert, \\
\end{aligned} \quad \begin{aligned}
L_{PE} &= \lVert E - P \rVert, \\
L_{QE} &= \lVert E - Q \rVert, \\
L_{RE} &= \lVert E - R \rVert, \\
\end{aligned} \quad \begin{aligned}
\varphi_{PQ} &= \angle P E Q \\
\varphi_{PR} &= \angle P E R \\
\varphi_{QR} &= \angle Q E R \\
\end{aligned}$$
The area of each triangular side is
$$\begin{aligned}
A_{PEQ} &= \frac{1}{2} L_{PE} L_{QE} \sin\varphi_{PQ} \\
A_{PER} &= \frac{1}{2} L_{PE} L_{RE} \sin\varphi_{PR} \\
A_{QER} &= \frac{1}{2} L_{QE} L_{RE} \sin\varphi_{QR} \\
\end{aligned} \tag{1}\label{None1}$$
On the other hand, using Heron's formula for the areas we have
$$\begin{aligned}
A_{PEQ} &= \frac{1}{4}\sqrt{ 4 L_{PE}^2 L_{QE}^2 - ( L_{PE}^2 + L_{QE}^2 - L_{PQ}^2 )^2 } \\
A_{PER} &= \frac{1}{4}\sqrt{ 4 L_{PE}^2 L_{RE}^2 - ( L_{PE}^2 + L_{RE}^2 - L_{PR}^2 )^2 } \\
A_{QER} &= \frac{1}{4}\sqrt{ 4 L_{QE}^2 L_{RE}^2 - ( L_{QE}^2 + L_{RE}^2 - L_{QR}^2 )^2 } \\
\end{aligned} \tag{2}\label{None2}$$
Combining $\eqref{None1}$ and $\eqref{None2}$, and multiplying each equation by 4, we have
$$\left\lbrace ~ \begin{aligned}
2 L_{PE} L_{QE} \sin\varphi_{PQ} = \sqrt{ 4 L_{PE}^2 L_{QE}^2 - ( L_{PE}^2 + L_{QE}^2 - L_{PQ}^2 )^2 } \\
2 L_{PE} L_{RE} \sin\varphi_{PR} = \sqrt{ 4 L_{PE}^2 L_{RE}^2 - ( L_{PE}^2 + L_{RE}^2 - L_{PR}^2 )^2 } \\
2 L_{QE} L_{RE} \sin\varphi_{QR} = \sqrt{ 4 L_{QE}^2 L_{RE}^2 - ( L_{QE}^2 + L_{RE}^2 - L_{QR}^2 )^2 } \\
\end{aligned} \right . \tag{3}\label{None3}$$
Because the angles are all positive and less than $180°$, the sines are all nonnegative, and both sides of each equation are nonnegative.  Thus, we can square both sides.  Simplifying and rearranging the terms in each equation, we get
$$\left\lbrace ~ \begin{aligned}
(L_{PE}^2 + L_{QE}^2 - L_{PQ}^2)^2 &= 2^2 L_{PE}^2 L_{QE}^2 (1 - (\sin\varphi_{PQ})^2) \\
(L_{PE}^2 + L_{RE}^2 - L_{PR}^2)^2 &= 2^2 L_{PE}^2 L_{RE}^2 (1 - (\sin\varphi_{PR})^2) \\
(L_{QE}^2 + L_{RE}^2 - L_{QR}^2)^2 &= 2^2 L_{QE}^2 L_{RE}^2 (1 - (\sin\varphi_{QR})^2) \\
\end{aligned} \right . \tag{4}\label{None4}$$
The rightmost term in each is equivalent to cosine of the same angle squared.  Since both sides of each equation are nonnegative, we can take the square root.  Rearranging the terms, we get
$$\left\lbrace ~ \begin{aligned}
L_{PE}^2 + L_{QE}^2 - 2 L_{PE} L_{QE} \cos\varphi_{PQ} - L_{PQ}^2 &= 0 \\
L_{PE}^2 + L_{RE}^2 - 2 L_{PE} L_{RE} \cos\varphi_{PR} - L_{PR}^2 &= 0 \\
L_{QE}^2 + L_{RE}^2 - 2 L_{QE} L_{RE} \cos\varphi_{QR} - L_{QR}^2 &= 0 \\
\end{aligned} \right . \tag{5}\label{None5}$$
which, as Aretino pointed out in a comment, we could have actually started with, as it is literally just the [cosine rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines) applied to each triangle.

Solving the first equation for $L_{QE}$ yields
$$L_{QE} = L_{PE} \cos\varphi_{PQ} \pm \sqrt{ L_{PQ}^2 - (L_{PE} \sin\varphi_{PQ})^2 } \tag{6a}\label{None6a}$$
and solving the second equation for $L_{RE}$ yields
$$L_{RE} = L_{PE} \cos\varphi_{PR} \pm \sqrt{ L_{PR}^2 - (L_{PE} \sin\varphi_{PR})^2 } \tag{6b}\label{None6b}$$
Substituting $L_{QE}$ and $L_{RE}$ to the third equation and solving for $L_{PE}$ yields two solutions each, one negative and one positive, but only the positive ones make physical sense (edge lengths are nonnegative).  Furthermore, choosing either sign for $L_{RE}$ yields the same positive $L_{PE}$, so there are really only two unique candidate $L_{PE}$.

The exact expressions when substituting $L_{QE}$ and $L_{RE}$ candidates to the third equation, with $L_{PE}$ the only unknown, are

```
+ + : sqrt(L_PQ^2 - L_PE^2*sin(phi_PQ)^2)*(2*L_PE*cos(phi_PQ) - 2*L_PE*cos(phi_PR)*cos(phi_RQ)) + sqrt(L_PR^2-L_PE^2*sin(phi_PR)^2)*(-2*sqrt(L_PQ^2-L_PE^2*sin(phi_PQ)^2)*cos(phi_RQ) - 2*L_PE*cos(phi_PQ)*cos(phi_RQ) + 2*L_PE*cos(phi_PR)) - 2*L_PE^2*cos(phi_PQ)*cos(phi_PR)*cos(phi_RQ) + 2*L_PE^2*cos(phi_PR)^2 - 2*L_PE^2*sin(phi_PQ)^2 - L_RQ^2 + L_PR^2 + L_PQ^2 = 0 $
+ - : sqrt(L_PQ^2 - L_PE^2*sin(phi_PQ)^2)*(2*L_PE*cos(phi_PQ) - 2*L_PE*cos(phi_PR)*cos(phi_RQ)) + sqrt(L_PR^2-L_PE^2*sin(phi_PR)^2)*( 2*sqrt(L_PQ^2-L_PE^2*sin(phi_PQ)^2)*cos(phi_RQ) + 2*L_PE*cos(phi_PQ)*cos(phi_RQ) - 2*L_PE*cos(phi_PR)) - 2*L_PE^2*cos(phi_PQ)*cos(phi_PR)*cos(phi_RQ) + 2*L_PE^2*cos(phi_PR)^2 - 2*L_PE^2*sin(phi_PQ)^2 - L_RQ^2 + L_PR^2 + L_PQ^2 = 0 $
- + : sqrt(L_PQ^2 - L_PE^2*sin(phi_PQ)^2)*(2*L_PE*cos(phi_PR)*cos(phi_RQ) - 2*L_PE*cos(phi_PQ)) + sqrt(L_PR^2-L_PE^2*sin(phi_PR)^2)*( 2*sqrt(L_PQ^2-L_PE^2*sin(phi_PQ)^2)*cos(phi_RQ) - 2*L_PE*cos(phi_PQ)*cos(phi_RQ) + 2*L_PE*cos(phi_PR)) - 2*L_PE^2*cos(phi_PQ)*cos(phi_PR)*cos(phi_RQ) + 2*L_PE^2*cos(phi_PR)^2 - 2*L_PE^2*sin(phi_PQ)^2 - L_RQ^2 + L_PR^2 + L_PQ^2 = 0 $
- - : sqrt(L_PQ^2 - L_PE^2*sin(phi_PQ)^2)*(2*L_PE*cos(phi_PR)*cos(phi_RQ) - 2*L_PE*cos(phi_PQ)) + sqrt(L_PR^2-L_PE^2*sin(phi_PR)^2)*(-2*sqrt(L_PQ^2-L_PE^2*sin(phi_PQ)^2)*cos(phi_RQ) + 2*L_PE*cos(phi_PQ)*cos(phi_RQ) - 2*L_PE*cos(phi_PR)) - 2*L_PE^2*cos(phi_PQ)*cos(phi_PR)*cos(phi_RQ) + 2*L_PE^2*cos(phi_PR)^2 - 2*L_PE^2*sin(phi_PQ)^2 - L_RQ^2 + L_PR^2 + L_PQ^2 = 0 $
```

In implicit form, after simplifying the expressions, Maxima describes the solutions as

```
L_PE^2 = sqrt(L_PQ^2 - L_PE^2*sin(phi_PQ)^2) * (2*L_PE*cos(phi_PQ) - 2*L_PE*cos(phi_PR)*cos(phi_QR))
       + sqrt(L_PR^2 - L_PE^2*sin(phi_PR)^2) * ( 2*sqrt(L_PQ^2 - L_PE^2*sin(phi_PQ)^2) * cos(phi_QR) - 2*L_PE*cos(phi_PQ)*cos(phi_QR) + 2*L_PE*cos(phi_PR))
       + 2*L_PE^2*cos(phi_PQ)*cos(phi_PR)*cos(phi_QR) + 2*L_PE^2*sin(phi_PQ)^2 - 2*L_PE^2*cos(phi_PR)^2 + L_QR^2 - L_PR^2

L_PE^2 = sqrt(L_PQ^2 - L_PE^2*sin(phi_PQ)^2) * (2*L_PE*cos(phi_PR)*cos(phi_QR) - 2*L_PE*cos(phi_PQ))
       + sqrt(L_PR^2 - L_PE^2*sin(phi_PR)^2) * (-2*sqrt(L_PQ^2 - L_PE^2*sin(phi_PQ)^2) * cos(phi_QR) - 2*L_PE*cos(phi_PQ)*cos(phi_QR) + 2*L_PE*cos(phi_PR))
       + 2*L_PE^2*cos(phi_PQ)*cos(phi_PR)*cos(phi_QR) + 2*L_PE^2*sin(phi_PQ)^2 - 2*L_PE^2*cos(phi_PR)^2 + L_QR^2 - L_PR^2
```

where `L_PE` is the only unknown variable, but appears on both sides of the equation.  I do not know if this can be massaged to an algebraic solution, or if these need to be solved numerically.

Substituting each candidate $L_{PE}$ to $\eqref{None6a}$ and $\eqref{None6b}$ yields a candidate triplet $L_{PE}$, $L_{QE}$, $L_{RE}$, which need to be verified to produce the correct angles $\varphi_{PQ}$, $\varphi_{PR}$, and $\varphi_{QR}$.

Verifying that $L_{PE} \gt 0$, $L_{QE} \gt 0$, $L_{RE} \gt 0$ (for a non-degenerate tetrahedron), and that they fulfill $\eqref{None5}$, is sufficient: it is equivalent to constructing the tetrahedron.

When a triplet $L_{PE}$, $L_{QE}$, $L_{RE}$ that fulfills $\eqref{None5}$ is found, the coordinates of $E$ are found via standard [trilateration](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3753574/806517) using $P$, $Q$, $R$, $L_{PE}$, $L_{QE}$, and $L_{RE}$.

Comment: Note that eq. $(5)$ can be directly derived from the cosine rule.

Comment: @Aretino: Whoops, how didn't I see that? :)  I'd better add a note about that.  Thanks!